# Is there a straightforward way to get the source/target point geometry of an edge?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to get the source or target point geometry of an edge?

It is still not clear to me how the source-target works. For example, if I use ST_StartPoint() to my edge, will it get the source or the target of the edge? Does it matter which direction I used when I digitised the line?

Also, I have set False on both 'directed' and 'reverse_cost' fields; does this mean that pgrouting will check an edge both ways? source/target and vice versa?

I hope I am making sense here!

Thanks in advance.
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to get the source or target point geometry of an edge?

Yes, source is ST_StartPoint(), target is ST_EndPoint().

> if I use ST_StartPoint() to my edge, will it get the source or the target of the edge?

The source geometry

> Does it matter which direction I used when I digitised the line?

Yes

> Also, I have set False on both 'directed' and 'reverse_cost' fields; does this mean that pgrouting will check an edge both ways? source/target and vice versa?

Yes